# Ethereum Ropsten chain not syncing in Parity Wallet

Tags: windows, ethereum

I am struggling with syncing my Ropsten chain in Parity wallet. I wanted to test deploying a contract, but the faucet issued the eth on a block I'm not on yet(faucet block: 1714049, my block: 1,705,822).

On Windows 10, I am running Parity using

```
./parity.exe --warp --chain ropsten --ntp-server time.windows.com:123 --mode active --tracing off --pruning fast --db-compaction hdd --cache-size 4096 >> /cygdrive/c/paritylogtest.txt &
```

Removing the ntp-server option makes no difference. I had been getting a NTP error, but that is no longer showing after using instructions here https://www.pretentiousname.com/timesync/
On the status page, it says Chain and Time synchronized. Sometimes for a second it will flash that Chain is not synchronized.

What am I doing wrong? Can I set my peers to match https://ropsten.etherscan.io?
 If I switch to Linux, how will i know it's working before downloading the whole thing?

Comment: What version of Parity are you using? Ropsten recently launched the Metropolis part 1 upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I had to upgrade to 1.7.2 and run 'parity --chain ropsten db kill' Re-downloading now and seems to have correct block height